# Raspberry Pi 2 External IP

Tags: pi-2

I am going to sound like an idiot but if I run ifconfig in my terminal to try and find my IP it just gives me 10.0.0.2 which is my internal IP not my external IP. How can I get my external IP as I am trying to setup a RTMP server.

Comment: What do you mean by external IP? Do you mean the IP of your router that connects to your ISP? If so use https://www.whatismyip.com/.

Comment: I have used that and got my IP but if I try to access the Nginx page using that address it doesnt work, if I use my internal address (10.0.0.20) and try to access the page it does work

Comment: First you are inside the LAN so you need to use the internal IP. Second if you want to connect from outside your LAN (home) you will need to forward the port to your Raspberry Pi.

Comment: Yep I was being an idiot, thanks for the help ahaha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run: `curl icanhazip.com`

It will directly give you your external IP address, as seen by `icanhazip`'s servers.